# Form validation - help with rules

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation

Hi I'm writing and app in PHP. I want to use jquery form validation but the situation I have  are 'from' and 'to' fields. If one of these used and the other is blank I want to stop the form submit.

So user can only submit the form if to and from are either both empty or both contain dates.

Here are the fields:

```
<table class="search-form">
<tr>
    <td><label>Client</label></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('client', $clients, $current_client);?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Date From: </label></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="from_date" class="datepicker" value="<?php echo $from; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Date To: </label></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="to_date" class="datepicker" value="<?php echo $to; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
</tr>
```

Can someone steer me in the right direction here.

Thanks,

Billy

Comment: @powtac - would adding more code make it any easier? What else would you like to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be something built into jQuery to handle this, but I can't think of it if there is. You could simply attach a function to the submit button that does some quick checking like this:

```
function(){ //attached to the $('form').submit
if (($("from_date").text == "" && $("to_date").text == "")
|| $("from_date").text != "" && $("to_date").text != ""))
    return true;
else
    return false; //return false should prevent the form from from being submitted
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you help me with how I would allow or stop the form submit?

Comment: instead of attaching the function to the click event as I said before you should attach it to the #('form').submit as Eugene suggested. I've edited the code to give you a better idea how to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: See the answer from "Eugene msc" for how to attach the function to the submit procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add form tag and then in jquery do

```
$('form').submit(function() {
//validation here
 if(success)return true;
   else return false;
});
```

return false means that default submit function is not launched